# Why my where query is not executed in controller?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to reach `items` table from `CategoriesController.php`, but I see in Laravel(5.3) Debugbar, that my query is not executed. Why? Here is my code:

```
# Http/Controllers/CategoriesController.php

use App\Category;
use App\Item;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

class CategoriesController extends Controller {

  public function show($id) {

    $items = \App\Item::where('id', $id); # <- This is not executed!

    $category = \App\Category::find($id);

    return view('categories.show', compact('category', 'items'));

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::where()` is chaining off of the query builder, however you never execute the request.

```
::where('id', $id)->first(); //if you only want the first result
//shorthand would be ::find($id);
```

Alternatively if you want every match:

```
::where('id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, it really works. Sorry - I'm new to Laravel... I have to wait 9 minutes to accept an answer

Comment: I came to Laravel from Ruby on Rails, there where() function executes without additional commands, this is why this misleaded me. Thank you bro!

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = \App\Item::where('id', $id);
```

This line is preparing a query for Eloquent to execute, but you never actually execute it.

Try running the following to execute the query and get all the results.

```
$items = \App\Item::where('id', $id)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `get()` or `first()` or `paginate` or `pluck()` or `find()` etc to execute the query. In this case you want to use `first()` method:

```
\App\Item::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Or just:

```
\App\Item::find($id);
```